# События клавиатуры

Tags: события, javascript

Есть строчка 
            document.body.onkeyup = function () {canvas1.style.zIndex = 4; }, которая меняет z-индекс canvas1, работает на отлично, но срабатывает на любую клавишу. Можно ли "заточить" ее на какую-то определенную, например, shift, и как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://learn.javascript.ru/keyboard-events

```
function (event){
    if( event.shiftKey ){
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Не сработало, причем я сделала
document.body.onkeyup = function (event){
    if( event.shiftKey ){
       canvas1.style.zIndex = 4;
    }
    else{alert(1);}
    } 
И при нажатии шифта, или любой другой клавиши, срабатывает alert

Comment: Потому что нужен [keydown][1], почитайте статью, там многое разжевано.

[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/gSxUg/

Comment: упс, я думала шифт только на keypress не работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать с использование jQuery
То есть
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on("keyup",function(e){
if (!e.shiftKey) return;
   ...
});
});
Удачи ;)